# Pearson product moment correlation coefficent, coefficient of determination and negative values

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, linear-regression

here is the formula I have:

$$R = \frac {    \frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i - \bar{x} \bar{y}   }           
{    \sqrt{ \frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2   \frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2  }}$$

Now assuming we have a set of measurements whose sample correlation coefficient is $R$.

Assuming the relationship (regression curve) : $$ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x $$ ( i think we assume the simple linear model), then we have that, given that $\beta_i$ are the MLE of their respective coefficient : $$ R = \hat{\beta}_1 \frac{ \sqrt{ n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2 }   } {    \sqrt{  n \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)^2 }} $$

which leads us to:

$$ R^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y} )^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1 x_i)^2 }{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2} $$

which is I guess is a well-known formula.

all of this can be found page 602 of the book "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and its applications" by R.J. Larsen and M.L. Marx.

> Here is my question. I'm not sure how to tackle this last equation.
>   $R^2$ should be positive, does that mean the numerator can't be
>   negative, why? Moreover, how do you interpret globally this expression?
>   Does it have some meaning? Since we are doing $$ \frac {A + B}{A},
>  $$I'm assuming it has some interesting meaning.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, you re firing really really fast

Comment: It just happened I was passing by… ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ R^2 = \frac{\sum^n (y_i - \bar{y} )^2 - \sum^n(y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1 x_i)^2 }{\sum^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2} $$
$$=1-\frac{\sum^n(y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1 x_i)^2 }{\sum^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2}.$$

I will assume that our regression weights are determined by the method of least squares. Then, the second term is always positive and smaller than $1$. It is positive because it is a fraction of the sum of squares. The value is smaller than $1$ because the regression equation $\hat{y}_i=\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1x_i$ is almost always closer to $y_i$ than the mean $\overline{y}$. Only if our observed outputs have the same constant values the regression equation will give the mean $\overline{y}=\hat{\beta}_0$ as the solution. This means that the deviations in the numerator are almost always smaller than the deviations in the denominator. Which implies that the second term is always smaller than $1$. Or to put it more simply your regression can always be as poor as the constant mean of the outputs $\overline{y}$.

The $R^2$ value can be interpreted as the ratio of the sum of squares for the regression

$$\text{SS}_\text{Reg}=\sum_{n=1}^N\left[\hat{y}_n - \overline{y}\right]^2$$

and the total sum of squares

$$\text{SS}_\text{Total}=\sum_{n=1}^N\left[y_n-\overline{y} \right]^2.$$

If our regression equation $\hat{y}_n$ is perfectly fitting the observed outputs $y_n$ then the $R^2$ value will have the value $1$. If the regression is only able to fit the mean then $R^2=0$ which indicates a very poor fit. Note, that the $R^2$ value is very liberal when $n$ is not much larger than the number of regression weights.